# Transformer: English -> Source Code Training Accuracy stuck 60% and validation 40%

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, transformer

I'm working on my final year project which is to write a model that takes as an input an english sentence and generate source code (currently testing on english->javascript dataset provided by CodeSearchNet) as output.

So, I decided to use Transformers as my model because I read many articles and it seemed that it is a good seq2seq model with good result.

I have used the transformer code provided by the Tensorflow documentation and I have applied few changes of course like now I'm using a pre-trained tokenizer called CodeBert which is pretrained on nl --> 6 programming language (java/javascript/python/....)

The problem I'm facing that when I run my training(50k training data,5k validation), after 20epochs my training accuracy gets stuck around 60-65% and my validation accuarcy around 40-45% I even tried to train for 30 more epochs but it is the same and result of generation is no where close to something correct. Here what it looks like :

English: generate a number from 1 to 10
Result :
function ( ) { var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0 ; var i = 0x0 = 0x0 & 0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, I have tried to play around with hyper-parameter but no result. I'm stuck I really need your advice if someone could help me and thanks in advance. here is my code:

Positional Encoding:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
class PositionalEncoding(layers.Layer):
def __init__(self):
    super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()

def get_angles(self, pos, i, d_model):
    angles = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i // 2)) / np.float32(d_model))
    return pos * angles

def call(self, inputs):
    seq_length = inputs.shape.as_list()[-2]
    d_model = inputs.shape.as_list()[-1]
    angles = self.get_angles(np.arange(seq_length)[:, np.newaxis], np.arange(d_model)[np.newaxis, :], d_model)
    angles[:, 0::2] = np.sin(angles[:, 0::2])
    angles[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angles[:, 1::2])
    pos_encoding = angles[np.newaxis, ...]
    return inputs + tf.cast(pos_encoding, tf.float32)
```

Multi-head Attention

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def scaled_dot_product_attention(queries,keys,values,mask):
    product = tf.matmul(queries,keys,transpose_b=True)
    keys_dim = tf.cast(tf.shape(keys)[-1],tf.float32)
    scaled_product = product/tf.math.sqrt(keys_dim)
    if mask is not None:
        scaled_product += (mask * -1e9)
    attention = tf.matmul(tf.nn.softmax(scaled_product,axis=-1),values)
    return attention


class MultiHeadAttention(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,nb_proj):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.nb_proj = nb_proj

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.d_model = input_shape[-1]
        assert self.d_model % self.nb_proj == 0

        self.d_proj = self.d_model // self.nb_proj

        self.query_lin = layers.Dense(units=self.d_model)
        self.key_lin = layers.Dense(units=self.d_model)
        self.value_lin = layers.Dense(units=self.d_model)

        self.final_lin = layers.Dense(units=self.d_model)

    def split_proj(self,inputs,batch_size):
        shape = (batch_size,-1,self.nb_proj,self.d_proj)
        splited_inputs = tf.reshape(inputs,shape=shape)
        return tf.transpose(splited_inputs,perm=[0,2,1,3])

    def call(self,queries,keys,values,mask):
        batch_size = tf.shape(queries)[0]

        queries = self.query_lin(queries)
        keys = self.key_lin(keys)
        values = self.value_lin(values)

        queries = self.split_proj(queries,batch_size)
        keys = self.split_proj(keys,batch_size)
        values = self.split_proj(values,batch_size)

        attention = scaled_dot_product_attention(queries,keys,values,mask)

        attention = tf.transpose(attention,perm=[0,2,1,3])

        concat_attention = tf.reshape(attention,shape=(batch_size,-1,self.d_model))

        output = self.final_lin(concat_attention)

        return output
```

Encoder Layer

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from TransformerArch import MultiHeadAttention


class EncoderLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout):
        super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.FFN_units = FFN_units
        self.nb_proj = nb_proj
        self.dropout = dropout

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.d_model = input_shape[-1]
        self.multi_head_attention = MultiHeadAttention.MultiHeadAttention(self.nb_proj)
        self.dropout_1 = layers.Dropout(rate=self.dropout)
        self.norm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(units=self.FFN_units, activation="relu")
        self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(units=self.d_model)
        self.dropout_2 = layers.Dropout(rate=self.dropout)
        self.norm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

    def call(self, inputs, mask, training):

        attention = self.multi_head_attention(inputs, inputs, inputs, mask)

        attention = self.dropout_1(attention, training=training)

        attention = self.norm_1(attention + inputs)

        outputs = self.dense_1(attention)

        outputs = self.dense_2(outputs)

        outputs = self.dropout_2(outputs)

        outputs = self.norm_2(outputs + attention)

        return outputs
```

Encoder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from TransformerArch import PositionalEncoding
from TransformerArch import EncoderLayer


class Encoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, nb_layers, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout, vocab_size, d_model, name="encoder"):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.nb_layers = nb_layers
        self.FFN_units = FFN_units
        self.nb_proj = nb_proj
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.d_model = d_model

        self.embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = PositionalEncoding.PositionalEncoding()
        self.dropout = layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)
        self.enc_layers = [EncoderLayer.EncoderLayer(FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout)
                           for _ in range(nb_layers)]

    def call(self, inputs, mask, training):
        outputs = self.embedding(inputs)
        outputs *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        outputs = self.pos_encoding(outputs)
        outputs = self.dropout(outputs, training)
        for i in range(self.nb_layers):
            outputs = self.enc_layers[i](outputs, mask, training)
        return outputs
```

Decoder Layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from TransformerArch import MultiHeadAttention


class DecoderLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.FFN_units = FFN_units
        self.nb_proj = nb_proj
        self.dropout = dropout

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.d_model = input_shape[-1]
        self.multi_head_attention_1 = MultiHeadAttention.MultiHeadAttention(self.nb_proj)
        self.dropout_1 = layers.Dropout(rate=self.dropout)
        self.norm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-3)

        self.multi_head_attention_2 = MultiHeadAttention.MultiHeadAttention(self.nb_proj)
        self.dropout_2 = layers.Dropout(rate=self.dropout)
        self.norm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-3)

        self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(units=self.FFN_units, activation="relu")
        self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(units=self.d_model)
        self.dropout_3 = layers.Dropout(rate=self.dropout)
        self.norm_3 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-3)

    def call(self, inputs, enc_outputs, mask_1, mask_2, training):
        attention = self.multi_head_attention_1(inputs, inputs, inputs, mask_1)

        attention = self.dropout_1(attention, training)
        attention = self.norm_1(attention + inputs)

        attention_2 = self.multi_head_attention_2(attention, enc_outputs, enc_outputs, mask_2)
        attention_2 = self.dropout_2(attention_2, training)
        attention_2 = self.norm_2(attention_2 + attention)


        outputs = self.dense_1(attention_2)
        outputs = self.dense_2(outputs)
        outputs = self.dropout_3(outputs, training)
        outputs = self.norm_3(outputs + attention_2)


        return outputs
```

Decoder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from TransformerArch import DecoderLayer
from TransformerArch import PositionalEncoding


class Decoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, nb_layers, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout, vocab_size, d_model, name="decoder"):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.nb_layers = nb_layers
        self.d_model = d_model

        self.embedding = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = PositionalEncoding.PositionalEncoding()
        self.dropout = layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)
        self.dec_layers = [DecoderLayer.DecoderLayer(FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout) for _ in range(nb_layers)]

    def call(self, inputs, enc_outputs, mask_1, mask_2, training):
        outputs = self.embedding(inputs)

        outputs *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))

        outputs = self.pos_encoding(outputs)

        outputs = self.dropout(outputs, training)

        for i in range(self.nb_layers):
            outputs = self.dec_layers[i](outputs, enc_outputs, mask_1, mask_2, training)

        return outputs
```

Transformer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from TransformerArch import Encoder
from TransformerArch import Decoder
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size_enc, vocab_size_dec, d_model, nb_layers, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout,
                 name="transfomer"):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.encoder = Encoder.Encoder(nb_layers, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout, vocab_size_enc, d_model)
        self.decoder = Decoder.Decoder(nb_layers, FFN_units, nb_proj, dropout, vocab_size_dec, d_model)
        self.last_linear = layers.Dense(units=vocab_size_dec)

    def create_padding_mask(self, seq):
        mask = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(seq, 1), tf.float32)
        return mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]

    def create_look_ahead_mask(self, seq):
        seq_len = tf.shape(seq)[1]
        look_ahead_mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((seq_len, seq_len)), -1, 0)
        return look_ahead_mask

    #def call(self, enc_inputs, dec_inputs, training):
    def call(self, inputs):
        enc_mask = self.create_padding_mask(inputs[0])
        dec_mask_1 = tf.maximum(self.create_padding_mask(inputs[1]), self.create_look_ahead_mask(inputs[1]))
        dec_mask_2 = self.create_padding_mask(inputs[0])
        enc_outputs = self.encoder(inputs[0], enc_mask, inputs[2])
        dec_outputs = self.decoder(inputs[1], enc_outputs, dec_mask_1, dec_mask_2, inputs[2])
        outputs = self.last_linear(dec_outputs)
        return outputs
```

Training Code:

```
from TransformerArch import Transformer
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import os
import DPPreLN, ValidationS


TF_CONFIG_ = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
TF_CONFIG_.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=TF_CONFIG_)

DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    # Hyper-parameters
    D_MODEL = 128  # 512 #128
    NB_LAYERS = 4  # 6 #4
    FFN_UNITS = 256  # 2048 #512
    NB_PROJ = 8  # 8
    DROPOUT = 0.1  # 0.1

    transformer = Transformer.Transformer(vocab_size_enc=50265, vocab_size_dec=50265, d_model=D_MODEL,
                                          nb_layers=NB_LAYERS,
                                          FFN_units=FFN_UNITS, nb_proj=NB_PROJ, dropout=DROPOUT)

    loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, reduction="none")


    def loss_function(target, pred):
        mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(target, 1)) #CodeBert pad Token ID is 1 not 0
        loss = loss_object(target, pred)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss.dtype)
        loss *= mask
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)


    def accuracy_function(real, pred):
        accuracies = tf.equal(real, tf.cast(tf.argmax(pred, axis=2), tf.int32))

        mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 1))
        accuracies = tf.math.logical_and(mask, accuracies)

        accuracies = tf.cast(accuracies, dtype=tf.int32)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=accuracies.dtype)
        return tf.reduce_sum(accuracies) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)


    train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_loss")
    train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_accuracy")

    valid_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="valid_loss")
    valid_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="valid_accuracy")


    class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
        def __init__(self, d_model, warmup_steps=4000):
            super(CustomSchedule, self).__init__()
            self.d_model = tf.cast(d_model, tf.float32)
            self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

        def __call__(self, step):
            arg1 = tf.math.rsqrt(step)
            arg2 = step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5)
            self.lr = tf.math.rsqrt(self.d_model) * tf.math.minimum(arg1, arg2)
            return self.lr

        def get_config(self):
            config = {
                'd_model': self.d_model,
                'warmup_steps': self.warmup_steps,
                'lr': self.lr
            }
            return config


    learning_rate = CustomSchedule(D_MODEL)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate ,beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-9)

    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(DIRNAME, "Checkpoint")  # path to pc

    ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(transformer=transformer, optimizer=optimizer)

    ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, checkpoint_path, max_to_keep=3)

    if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
        ckpt.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
        print("Latest Checkpoint restored !")

    EPOCHS = 50
    dataset = DPPreLN.prepareData()
    valid_set = ValidationS.prepareData()
    
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        print("Start of epoch {}".format(epoch + 1))
        start = time.time()
        train_loss.reset_states()
        train_accuracy.reset_states()
        for (batch, (enc_inputs, targets)) in enumerate(dataset):
            dec_inputs = targets[:, :-1]
            dec_outputs_real = targets[:, 1:]
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                predictions = transformer([enc_inputs, dec_inputs, True])
                loss = loss_function(dec_outputs_real, predictions)
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))
            train_loss(loss)
            train_accuracy(accuracy_function(dec_outputs_real, predictions))
            
            if batch % 50 == 0:
                print(
                    "Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f} Accuracy {:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, batch,
                                                                           train_loss.result(),
                                                                           train_accuracy.result() * 100,
                                                                           ))

        # VALIDATION TEST
        print("***** VALIDATION PART *****")
        valid_loss.reset_states()
        valid_accuracy.reset_states()
        for (batch, (enc_inputs, targets)) in enumerate(valid_set):
            dec_inputs = targets[:, :-1]
            dec_outputs_real = targets[:, 1:]
            predictions = transformer([enc_inputs, dec_inputs, False])
            loss = loss_function(dec_outputs_real, predictions)
            valid_loss(loss)
            valid_accuracy(accuracy_function(dec_outputs_real, predictions))
            if batch % 50 == 0:
                print(
                    "Validation :Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f} Accuracy {:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, batch,
                                                                                       valid_loss.result(),
                                                                                       valid_accuracy.result() * 100,
                                                                                       ))

        # SAVE CHECKPOINT/MODEL
        ckpt_save_path = ckpt_manager.save()
        print("Saving checkpoint for epoch {} at {} ".format(epoch + 1, ckpt_save_path))
        print("Time taken for 1 epoch : {} secs\n".format(time.time() - start))
        transformer.save_weights(os.path.join(DIRNAME, "Models", "Weight"))
        print("*****************************************")
        print("*   Model Has Been Successfully Saved   *")
        print("*****************************************")


    print(transformer.summary())
```

Comment: Hi @Abdelhamid, welcome to the site. Here are some pieces of advice: 1) If you are using a standard Transformer implementation, just trust it and don't paste it here; don't expect people to review a full Transformer implementation 2) You did not include your inference code, but the errors shown suggest you are using greedy decoding; if you are actually using it, consider using beam search instead.

Comment: @noe thanks for your advices and sorry for the late response, I'm beginner in the field of ml and deep learning and this project means alot to me and I'm running out of time because I spent a lot training the model tweaking the hyper-parameter but I don't know why I cannot get good accuracy so could you please guide me with opinion. I checked the inference code and I'm 90% sure that I'm using a greedy decoder because I'm using the argmax to get the word with the highest prob and I wanted to apply the beam search but I don't know how to implement it to fit tensorflow transformer version